# Java Mockito one test causes another to fail

Tags: java, mockito, assert

```
@Test
    public void onConnectionCompletedTest() {
        connectionProvider.initialize();
        connectionProvider.addEventObserver(SocketEvent.Type.SOCKET_CONNECT, mockedObserver);
        connectionProvider.onConnectionCompleted(mockedChannel);

        verify(mockedObserver).socketEventObserved(socketEventCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(SocketEvent.Type.SOCKET_CONNECT, socketEventCaptor.getValue().getType());
    }


@Test
    public void onConnectionClosedTest() {
        connectionProvider.initialize();
        connectionProvider.addEventObserver(SocketEvent.Type.SOCKET_DISCONNECT, mockedObserver);
        connectionProvider.onConnectionClosed(mockedChannel);

        verify(mockedObserver).socketEventObserved(socketEventCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(SocketEvent.Type.SOCKET_DISCONNECT, socketEventCaptor.getValue().getType());
    }
```

The problem is when I run both of these tests, the 2nd one fails. But if I comment out

```
verify(mockedObserver).socketEventObserved(socketEventCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(SocketEvent.Type.SOCKET_CONNECT, socketEventCaptor.getValue().getType());
```

then the 2nd test will pass. There's a lot of different classes/methods involved in this so hopefully this is enough information to be able to come up with an explanation.

The error I get:

```
wanted but not invoked:
mockedObserver.socketEventObserved(
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at com.company.cnx.cip.io.ConnectionProviderTest.onConnectionClosedTest(ConnectionProviderTest.java:188)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

My question exactly: What could be happening that when I @Ignore the first test, the 2nd will pass?

EDIT: I have an @Before class that's important.

```
@Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(json);
        configurationService.loadConfiguration(jsonElement, "id");
        AppContext.getContext().applyConfiguration(configurationService);
        connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.newInstance();

    }
```

You can ignore everything that isn't the first and last line of it. I make a new ConnectionProvider object, so I would think that one test shoudldn't affect another, because they're operating on two separate objects.

Comment: Do you reset the mock on test initialize? Also, you may also want to create  a new instance of the class under test.

Comment: New to posting on this website, not sure if this will format correctly.

@Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(json);
        configurationService.loadConfiguration(jsonElement, "id");
        AppContext.getContext().applyConfiguration(configurationService);
        connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.newInstance();

    }

I edited my main post.

Comment: You're using MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(), do your mocks annotated with '@Mock' annotation?

Comment: Yes I do. The thing that confuses me is that if I @Ignore the first test (that works perfectly fine btw) then the 2nd test will run fine. So clearly I'm doing something in the 1st test that messes up the 2nd, but I'm not sure what that could be. Both of the tests work independently of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more straightforward than you think: The test works when you comment out those lines because `socketEventObserved` is not getting called when it's the second test of the run. This is probably a problem with code that you haven't posted above.

Since it seems that the culprit may be buried in an impractical volume of code, here are a few debugging tips and general sources of test pollution:

- First and foremost, set a breakpoint everywhere that `socketEventObserved` is called, and compare between single-test runs and multi-test runs. If you see the same behavior Mockito sees, then it's not Mockito.
- As it turned out to be in this case, keep an eye out for actions that may occur on other threads (particularly to listeners). Using a [Mockito timeout](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22) can help there:

  ```
  verify(mockedObserver, timeout(2000))
      .socketEventObserved(socketEventCaptor.capture());
  ```
- You seem to be working with I/O channels, which sometimes involve buffering or flushing policies that can be triggered only when a certain number of tests are run, or if tests are run in certain order. Make sure that your @Before method fully resets state, including any modes or buffers that your code may touch.
- You interact with `AppContext.getInstance()` and `ConnectionProvider.newInstance()`, both of which are static method calls. I'm less worried about the latter, unless it conserves instances in spite of its name, but the former may not take kindly to multiple initializations. In general, in your system-under-test, keep an eye out for writes to global state.
- Mockito itself keeps static state. Mockito keeps its internal state static and thread-scoped (through ThreadLocal), and at times a test can leave Mockito in an invalid internal state that it cannot detect (because an operation is half-completed, for instance). Add an @After method to detect this case:

  ```
  @After public void checkMockito() { Mockito.validateMockitoUsage(); }
  ```

  ...or switch to using `MockitoRule` or `MockitoJUnitRunner`, which do this and `initMocks(this)` automatically.
- Finally, Mockito isn't perfect: It uses proxy objects to override methods, which also means it will silently fail to mock `final` methods and some non-`public` methods that work with nested classes (as those require the compiler to generate synthetic methods you can't see). If your `mockedObserver` has any final or limited-visibility methods, it may cause real code and mocked code to interact in a way that makes the system's behavior hard-to-predict.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. It turns out it was being wonky because multiple threads were going on at once, so I just told it to sleep for a second. Currently looking if there's a way built in to Junit to do that.

Comment: @Josh `verify` can take a second parameter, which includes settings like invocation count. `timeout` sounds particularly handy for your case; it'll wait a specified number of milliseconds for your method call to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figure there's probably a better way than telling it to timeout, but it works so that's the solution I'm going with honestly.